# Not getting username from Firebase database

Tags: java, android

My app is sending user name according to the below code

```
  mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new 
  OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){


                        currentUserUid=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("MyUserList");
                        
  myRef.child(usernameInput).child(currentUserUid).child("username").setValue(usernameInput);

                        sendUserToLoginActivity();
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Account Created Successfully", 
  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        loadingBar.dismiss();

                    }
```

Now i have to get the username from Firebase database in another activity. I have tried the below way but **every time the 'score' is passing to database but not the username**. I don't want change the username setting way (above code) because i am checking duplicate username on user registration. How can i get the current username?

```
  private String currentUserUid;
  private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
  private String name;



  public void finisHere(){

       
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Score");
         String key=myRef.push().getKey();

        //......................
        currentUserUid= mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        DatabaseReference cUserNameRef = database.getReference("MyUserList");

        cUserNameRef.child(currentUserUid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new 
 ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot:snapshot.getChildren()){
                   // String name="";
                    name=dataSnapshot.child("username").getValue(String.class);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
        savingScoreModel scoreModel=new savingScoreModel(score,name);
        myRef.child(key).setValue(scoreModel);
        Intent intent =new 
        Intent(liveQuestionActivity.this,MainActivity.class);

        Toast.makeText(this, currentUserUid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //Toast is working
        startActivity(intent);
        finishAffinity();


    }
```

i am verifying the duplicate user name by the below code.

```
  private  void DuplicateUserName(){
        final DatabaseReference rootRef = 
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference userNameRef = 
 rootRef.child("MyUserList").child(usernameInput);
        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if(!dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    //create new user
                    //Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "success", 
 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   /* FirebaseDatabase database = 
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                    DatabaseReference myRef = 
 database.getReference("MyUserList");
                    
 myRef.child(usernameInput).child("username").setValue(usernameInput);

                    */
                    CreateNewAccount();


                }
                else {
                    UserName.setError("This username already taken");
                    UserName.requestFocus();
                    loadingBar.dismiss();
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, 
databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        userNameRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
    }
```

Comment: Remove the for loop and try this name=""+snapshot.child("username").getValue();

Comment: Result same brother.

Comment: savingScoreModel scoreModel=new savingScoreModel(score,name); this needs to be inside the onDataChange

Comment: This one as well   myRef.child(key).setValue(scoreModel);

Comment: yes, It is working. Thanks brother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Username was Uploaded to `"MyUserList"/usernameInput/currentUserUid/"username"`

But you are fetching `"MyUserList"/currentUserUid/"username"`

So, try this for uploading:

`myRef.child("MyUserList").child(currentUserUid).child("username").setValue(usernameInput);`

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask for clarifications...

EDIT: Edited after @Farhad's doubts

```
DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("MyUserList");

        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                  
                    //TODO: Here are your UserNames

                    }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please take look at my edit. I am checking the username that way. if i change code in according to your suggestion then how can check the duplicate username?

Comment: @Farhad `UID`s don't repeat. But `Name` can repeat. What is the need for checking duplicate `UserName`?

Comment: i need to show the exam score for each user in list view. That's why i need the username be unique.

Comment: @Farhad Then, get all the child values from `"MyUserList"/` and check for duplication.

Comment: could you please put here a single line how to start? it would be better understanding

Comment: Many thanks for your efforts. the solution given by  @Laurentiu Daniel is working. By the way i have imported my userlist for duplicate comparing as i did before and i add an extra  field which was told by you at first. Thanks again

Comment: @Farhad Happy to hear that. Thank You!